# XPath selector for dynamic ID

Tags: xpath

I have been trying to find a good XPath selector for the below HTML, there is a dynamic ID. I need to select in my Selenium IDE the option from that list 02 but it fails because the ID is dynamic.

Please help!!!

```html
<select class="c-select__input c-select" id="uf5rwnhtsy" required="">
  <option class="c-select__option" value="##">HH</option>
  <option class="c-select__option" value="01">01</option>
  <option class="c-select__option" value="02">02</option>
  <option class="c-select__option" value="03">03</option>
  <option class="c-select__option" value="04">04</option>
  <option class="c-select__option" value="05">05</option>
  <option class="c-select__option" value="06">06</option>
  <option class="c-select__option" value="07">07</option>
  <option class="c-select__option" value="08">08</option>
  <option class="c-select__option" value="09">09</option>
  <option class="c-select__option" value="10">10</option>
  <option class="c-select__option" value="11">11</option>
  <option class="c-select__option" value="12">12</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can't you select by class name?

Answer (score 1):

Use classname

```
//*[contains(@class, 'c-select__input c-select')]
```

Or be more specific

```
//select[contains(@class, 'c-select__input c-select')]
```

Or if you can't use class name you have to start upper from the tree, select something that is not changing and use the xpath to go down the tree until you hit the select component. For example consider the following:

```
//*[@id="hello"]//select
```

Or if you have access to the source code just add selector that is not changing. For example

```
data-testautomation="myElement"

//*[@data-testautomation="myElement"]
```

Comment: this one //*[contains(@class, 'c-select__input c-select')]  works,

 but how can i click  the value 02 or 03??  would it be like ?

//*[contains(@class, 'c-select__input c-select')] [02] ??

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by

xpath=//select[contains(@class, 'c-select__input c-select')]/option[8]